# Need ideas on testing Screen Recording feature like zoom

Tags: manual-testing, testcase

We have recently launched screen recording feature on our web app.

We provide support for browsers like Chrome, Safari and Edge to record/film the computer screen.

We would like to know your opinions/ideas for testing this features.

What can be possible tests that we can perform?

What can be possible/probable risks associated with this feature?

Are there common bugs in other similar services that we may encounter in our feature?

Comment: What tests have you come up with?

Answer (score 1):

Here some ideas;

1. Test with selected tab only, and make sure that when you switch to another tab, it does not get recorded.
2. Test the recovery testing, when a test is in progress and browser crashes, what happens?
3. Test the recording for more than 30 minutes.
4. Analyze the file size of recording.
5. Test while muting the mic or audio and with audio.

Answer (score 1):

Below are some additional test cases related to screen recording testing that is being used by QA in software testing services company:-

- User should be able to open and launch screen recorder.
- User should be able to select region to record the screen.
- User should be able to   resize the region selector.
- User should be able to pause the recording User should be able to resume the
  recording and recording should continue from paused area.
- User should be bale to stop the recording and save it.
- User should be able to cancel the recording.
- User should be able to save the recording in local drive.
- User should be able to play the recording.
- User should be able to record the screen audio if audio feature is enabled